# choosing between inheritence and type field

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, database-design, django-forms

I don't know if this is the right place to post this question, but here it is: 
I have an Answer object, an Answer can have multiple types (image, article, map, ..), each type has a form to show to the user so he can insert his answer.

I'm confused between these 2 options:

1- create a class answer and class type, answer class has many fields, and I create many forms, a form for each type of answer, and call the form when a user selects a specific type.

```
class answer(models.Model):
    name = fields.CharField(...)
    type = fields.ForeignKey(Type,...)
```

2- create a class answer, and a class for each type of answer that inherit from answer class.

What is the optimal way for MVC architecture and for the database?

I'm using MongoDB as a database.

Thanks.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: What did you learn googling re site:stackoverflow.com django mongodb (subtypes OR inheritance), etc?